# Drupal How to add .active class in to main menu

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7

How to add .active class in to main menu, when function `"theme"_links___"name-menu"`?

eg:

```
function socialzin_links__footer_menu($variables) {
    $html = "<ul>\n";

    foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {

        $html .= "<li>".l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link)."</li>";

    }

    $html .= "  </ul>\n";

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really Drupal specific except for the use of `current_path()` which I think is correct in this instance:

```
if($link['href'] == current_path()){ $class = "active" }
$html .= "<li class=".$class.">".l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link)."</li>";
```

Also see https://www.drupal.org/node/165273

Comment: if I has menu level? I add class acvtive how? when I need active li.parent and li.child

Comment: Same premise - the href value should still match the `current_path()` or whatever variable you have that represents the current ("active") page